# Как получить подтверждение платежа на сайте после оплаты методом "банковский платеж"

Tags: веб-программирование, платежи

Добрый день.
Есть сайт на OpenCart с методами оплаты paypal и bank transfer. После оплаты через paypal у заказа статус "оплачено". После оплаты через Bank Transfer у заказа статус "ожидаю оплаты". Каким образом при оформлении заказа через Bank Transfer можно узнать в автоматическом режиме,  что пользователь перевел средства на счет в банке и изменить статус заказа на "оплачено"? Платежная система Mollie.

Comment: Не знаю про все платежные системы, но те, для которых я делал, после оплаты шлют на указанный в кабинете или еще каким то образом URL запрос о подтверждении оплаты.

Comment: При оплате сразу после оформления заказа или в случае, когда оплата происходит через 1-2 дня?

Comment: Я так понимаю сразу после оформления приходит "ожидаю оплаты", в этом случае через 1-2 дня. Вообще в любое время =) Главное, чтобы сайт мог принять этот запрос и обработать.

Comment: у каких платежных систем, с которыми вы работали это возможно?

Comment: вот пример. https://oplata.tinkoff.ru/landing/develop/plug/http

Comment: Спасибо. Т.е. при выборе оплаты через банковский платеж выдается номер счета для клиента и по нему после оплаты проверяется оплачен ли счет. И после этого отправляется подтверждение на сайт, правильно?

Comment: да. после регистрации заказа в платежном сервисе он ожидает оплату. как только оплата прошла он шлет на сайт запрос

Comment: Спасибо, буду уточнять у техподдержки Mollie